# Can I have a JavaScript partial in Ruby on Rails? Partial is trying to render in HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function that simple selects all of the checkboxes on the current page, creates a form, and submits it automatically.

Instead of repeating the same exact JavaScript code on every single view, I want to try to just have a shared partial.

Here's all I have thus far:

```
#views/shared/_delete_multiple_items.js.erb
alert("<%= random_variable %>");
```

.

```
#views/users/index.html.erb
...
<script>
  function deleteMulitpleUsers() {
    <%= render 'shared/delete_multiple_items', :locals => {:random_variable => "Hello World" %>
  }
</script>
```

It looks like Rails is trying to render the partial in HTML though, if I understand this error correctly:

> Missing partial shared/_delete_multiple_items with {:locale=>[:en],
> :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html,
> :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:

I've tried to include `:formats => :js` with render, like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/delete_multiple_items', :locals => {:random_variable => "Hello World", :formats => :js %>
```

but I still get the same exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because server responding format is html, not javascript. Setting response format is done in controller so putting `format: :js` in templates won't work. Try these steps and see if they work for you.

1. Rename `_delete_multiple_items.js.erb` to
   `_delete_multiple_items.html.erb`
2. Put `alert("<%= random_variable %>");` inside `<script>` tag
3. In `index.html.erb`, remove all js related code and just do `<%=
   render 'shared/delete_multiple_items', :locals => {:random_variable
   => "Hello World" %>`

Comment: This did the trick for me. I'm not sure why I was specifically trying to load a JS file when I could have just simply loaded a normal partial, and included JS in it within the `<script>` tag. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
<%= render 'shared/delete_multiple_items', :locals => {:random_variable => "Hello World" %>
```

to this:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/delete_multiple_items', formats: :js, :locals => {:random_variable => "Hello World"} %>
```

`partial:` at the beginning to tell rails to look for a partial and `formats: :js` to tell rails to look for a js file (note that `formats` is NOT a child of `locals`)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a j on your js.erb file?

```
#views/shared/_delete_multiple_items.js.erb
alert("<%= j random_variable %>");
```